# How to mix a lot of audio files with NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio, mixing

For example, I have 5 audio files. And, I want to combine these files with C# NAudio.

```
<------- A.wav ------->    <---- B.wav ---->
      <---- C.wav ---->  <-- D.wav --> <- E.wav ->
```

I goggled but I can find a solution which apply this situation.

```
<----- A.wav ----->
<-- B.wav -->
<------ C.wav ------>
```

How can I combine a lot of audio files with each length and position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `MixingSampleProvider`
Use an `AudioFileReader` for each file. Then use the `DelayBy` extension on `ISampleProvider` to insert silence at the start of each file so they begin at the correct position.